# Laravel relationship returns items twice

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

I have categories and products in Laravel 5.5
Each product has a category and categories can have parent categories. I want to get all children products of a category when it's showed. Example: Clothes is a cateogry and has subcategories like shirts, jackets etc. and I when it's clicked on the Clothes category I want to show all products which have the shirts or jackets category. 
Here is my Category.php model:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

public function getAllProducts()
{
     $products = $this->products;

     foreach ($this->children as $child) {
        foreach ($child->products as $product) {
           $products[] = $product;
         }
      }

     return $products;
}
```

In my case I have three products which are "cloth1", "cloth2" and "shirt1". "cloth1" and "cloth2" belongs to the clothes category and "shirt1" belongs to the shirts category which is subcategory of clothes. So when I'm on the clothes category page I want to show all products ("cloth1", "cloth2" and "shirt1")
But in the view

```
{{dd($category->getAllProducts())}}
```

returns "cloth1", "cloth2", "shirt1", "shirt1" (it returns the shirt twice). Any idea why and how to fix this ?

**EDIT:** When I try `$category->products` on the clothes category it returns "cloth1" and "cloth2" and when I try it on the shirts category it returns "shirt1" only once (which is how it should be)

Comment: Is that a typo on missing `()` on `$this->products` and `$this->children`?

Comment: No. As far as I know laravel relationships work that way, brackets are only necessary when the function does not return  a relationship.

Comment: Ok confusing lol, so could it be that because `$products` will already contain an array, your simply adding the same values again in the loop `$products[]`, perhaps rename the return array to something else. Try `dd()`ing in the loop to see what its doing.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the array before the foreach contains the current "clothes" category "cloth1" and "cloth2" and the foreach adds each product of each of the children to the array

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I already did that before asking the question. I removed the foreach and let it only return `$this->products` and it returned only "cloth1" and "cloth2". I've also `dd()`ied the children and it returned "shirts" and when I tried `$category->products` on "shirts" it returned "shirt1" only once which is what it should do

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem using the `contains()` method
the function now looks like this:

```
public function getAllProducts()
{
    $products = $this->products;

    foreach ($this->children as $child) {
        foreach ($child->products as $product) {
            if (!$products->contains($product)) {
                $products[] = $product;
            }
        }
    }

    return $products;
}
```

But I still don't know why it returns "shirt1" twice if I don't use `contains`